# ':app:lintVitalRelease' error when generating signed apk

Tags: java, android, gradle

I've tried to upload my apk on google play and encountered an error message: "You uploaded a debuggable APK. For security reasons you need to disable debugging before it can be published in Google Play. Learn more about debuggable APKs."

Then I wrote `android:debuggable="false"` in my manifest and tried again. I've encountered the same error, so I've set the build variant from my module to release and tried generated an apk again, but this time, this error is generated:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.
  To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
          // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
          // but continue the build even when errors are found:
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
```

Comment: All answers seem to be either not to check for errors or not to abort on errors, but what about finding the problem and correcting it??? Android Studio shows no information about what is wrong... Any one was able to fix this with out ignoring errors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203415/error-while-generating-signed-apk-when-i-use-google-map go on this page fr answer. its work for me

Comment: "but what about finding the problem and correcting it???" I thought same but I always overlooked 'Inspection Results' tab on the bottom bar and also build\report folder contents. Please check.

Comment: build/report folder is a very good tip. For me the problem was missing translations, and it was clear from the html report.

Comment: on the error google give you the solution, why didn't you try this???? at first try to understand the error as well as error message

Comment: I did answer this question in the following link, and it is working perfect https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098494/error-when-generate-signed-apk/52140460#52140460

Comment: downgrading my android gradle work for me. ( " com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2 " )

Answer (score 447, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend turning off the lint checks, they're there for a reason. Instead, check what the error is and fix it.

The error report is saved to `[app module]/build/reports/lint-results-yourBuildName-fatal.html`. You can open this file in a browser to read about the errors.

It would be nice if Gradle could make it a little more clear where the error report is generated.

Comment: Agree, it's much better to correct the error! It is also possible to generate the report manually with `gradlew lint` or via an IDE, see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint

Comment: yes, rright direction. Moreover errors report in that html was well described and the errors were addressed ok, so I just corrected them with ease!

Comment: yes it's very annoying when it says `fix the issues identified by lint` but doesn't actually shows those errors or path to report...

Comment: This must be the accepted answer. Disabling lint is not a good solution.

Comment: in my case the error was `MissingTranslation: Incomplete translation` - question for Google: **why isn't this shown in Android Studio??** It's called a `integrated development environment` for a reason.

Comment: This works! I had an error in a layout where an id doesn't exist. Thanks

Comment: in my case autogenerated dimens for large and xlarge config were missing some of the values, would never find out if you did not point me where to look. Big thank you sir.

Comment: Thank you , when I check the report I found multiple ID in one layout caused this problem

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, I was lucky to browse the page down! Somebody should mark the answer as the good one

Comment: running `gradlew lint --debug` in Android studio Terminal will show you the path where the error report is saved

Comment: Thank you very much for tip. In my case I had fragment registered in Manifest as activity. Build was working fine unless I tried to sign APP. In report I was able to find exact problem.

Comment: There is not report folder!

Comment: No report folder, and the report folder I could find with the files are empty.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly

Answer (score 224):

I had this problem and solved it by adding:

```
lintOptions { 

    checkReleaseBuilds false

}
```

to my `build.gradle` file within the `android{ }` section.

Comment: This doesn't have any other side effects on the application right?

Comment: No, turning lint off will not cause any side effects on the application. Lint is a code-analysis tool and the error mentioned here caused by setting the debuggable property can be viewed in detail in the "lint-results-release-fatal.html" file in the build/outputs folder.

Comment: Had trouble adding an android {} section to my top-level build.grade file; so followed some other advice and added this to my build.grade file at the level of the app, i.e. one folder further down, where the android section was already present.

Comment: *Warning:* This simply disables the lint checks. It'd be better to at least take a look on the errors before disabling them. In my case, they were about some missing strings for specific languages.
Hit "Analyze" -> "Inspect code .."

Comment: I don't recommend this. In my case ignoring these warnings would cause crashes at run-time caused by missing resources. Please review lint-results-release-fatal.html and fix all the issues.

Comment: The path to `lint-results-release-fatal.html` is `app -> build -> reports`

Comment: i dont have an android section in build.gradle

Comment: I do not recommend this because it excludes all other errors also while creating release build so please do not use this.
It's better to solve error from build->reports->lint-results-release-fatal.html and solve error.

Comment: it gave white screen in my case. -1

Answer (score 83):

if you want to find out the exact error go to the following path in your project: /app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html(or .xml). The easiest way is if you go to the xml file, it will show you exactly what the error is including its position of the error in your either java class or xml file. Turning off the lint checks is not a good idea, they're there for a reason. Instead, go to:

```
    /app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html or 
    /app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.xml
```

and fix it.

In Kotlin is different. First you need to set the following code in Android section of build.gradel of the app folder.

```
     android {
          :
          lintOptions {
            baseline(file("lint-baseline.xml"))
          }
      }
```

Then run lint from the IDE (Analyze > Inspect Code) or from the command line as follows.

```
      $ ./gradlew lintDebug
```

...

The output prints the location of the lint-baseline.xml file within app folder but sometimes within app/src folder as well /app/lint-baseline.xml

Comment: This is way better than just ignore the errors and move on.  And the HTML file is so easy to understand the problem.

Comment: i found the problem in   /app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.xml.   thanks

Comment: There is not report folder!

Comment: @roghayeh hossein if you are using kotlin, You won't find report folder. There is another way of finding your lint files. I just updated my answers, you can check it back.

Answer (score 51):

Make sure you defined all the translations in all the `string.xml` files

Answer (score 43):

In case that you may trying to locate where the problem is, I found mine in the following path of my project: */app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html*(or .xml).

Hope this helps!

Comment: both are files are empty for me.

Answer (score 38):

I have faced same issue when creating signed apk from android studio. I just change little bit change on **build.gradle** file inside **android {}**

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had a similar issue.
Execution failed for task ‘:app:lint***Release’.
> org.picocontainer.MutablePicoContainer.registerComponentInstance(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/picocontainer/ComponentAdapter;

Answer (score 33):

**How to find error details**

Analyze -> Inspect Code

[image]

Then in Inspection Results you will see an error

[image]

In my case build failed due to unresolved javadoc reference in Google IAP

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To all the people who suggested to disable the lint checking, that is just a work around. It is still better to fix the error than skip it. Skipping lint checks should only be done in very specific cases and not all the time. AGAIN, THAT SHOULD BE DONE RARELY OR EVEN NOT AT ALL.

Answer (score 22):

```
***Try this***

 buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 18):

You can find more info choosing assemble from gradle build tab:[image]

**EDIT 2022:**

You can run after clicking elephant button:

```
gradle assembleDebug
```

Comment: this is the actual answer, go to the assemble in app, in gradle window and run it by double clicking, Android studio will tell you exactly what it was poping.

Comment: Oh my god... thanks! That one saved me a lot of time! :D

Comment: I got, `lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}` and i added it but i got the same error in every time i build a release

Answer (score 12):

Try These 3 lines in your app.gradle file.

```
android {
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
```

Comment: @justColbs might be you face another issue. Post your issue with log cat may  be some one guide you properly.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me, I just modified my BuildTypes like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        android {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
                // but continue the build even when errors are found:
                abortOnError false
            }
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Add this inside android {}
build.gradle(Module:App)

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
```

Answer (score 8):

My problem was a missing translation. I had a settings.xml that was not translated as it was not needed, so I had to add `"translatable="false"` to the strings:

`<string translatable="false" name="stringname">This string doesn't need translation</string>`

Answer (score 8):

Just find the error reason in here and fix it.

```
yourProject/app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.xml
```

Comment: you should know what exact error and recertify. thank you.

Comment: I found `TargetSdkVersion No Longer Supported:  Google Play requires that apps target API level 26 or higher.` in my log, i.e. can't set `targetSdkVersion` 25.

Answer (score 7):

My problem was a missing translation. I had a settings.xml that was not translated as it was not needed, so I had to add "translatable="false" to the strings:

```
<string translatable="false" name="stringname">This string doesn't need translation</string>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Solve this Issue Using this in build.gradle (app) File Inside main Android { inside }**

```
  buildTypes {
      //  crunchPngs false // or true   when png error
        release {
            lintOptions {
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As many people have suggested, it is always better to try and fix the error from the source. check the lint generated file

```
/app/build/reports/lint-results-release-fatal.html
```

read the file and you will be guided to where the error is coming from. Check out mine: the error came from improper view constraint.

Answer (score 3):

***Try below code***

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        lintOptions {
            disable 'MissingTranslation'
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
        minifyEnabled false
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows -> references ->Android->lint error checking.

un tick Run full error.......

[image]

Comment: Very pretty, but where is this window from please? I could not find it in Android Studio...

Answer (score 2):

**Go to build.gradle(Module:app)**

```
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
    // but continue the build even when errors are found:
    abortOnError false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove that statement from your manifest altogether, Eclipse will handle that for you on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was related to minimum target API level that is required by Google Play. It was set less than 26.

Issue disappeared when I set minimum target API level to 26.

Answer (score 1):

```
    lintOptions {
      checkReleaseBuilds false
      abortOnError false
    }
```

The above code can fix the problem by ignoring it, but it may result in crashing the app as well.

The good answer is in the following link:

[Error when generate signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098494/error-when-generate-signed-apk/52140460#52140460)

Answer (score 1):

Don't disable the lint option

Check the Lint Report for error and warning

PATH:

> **YourAppProjectFolder\app\build\reports**

Solve all error and warning:)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code in project level gradle file for generating apk overwriting over errors

Answer (score 0):

This problem came to me when I updated the `Android Gradle Plugin Version` to `4.0.1` and the `Gradle version` to `6.1.1`.

If someone is in a hurry, just downgrade the `Gradle Plugin Version` to `3.6.3` and the `Gradle version` to `5.6.4`. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading gradle distribution url to,

```
// android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip
```

and upgrading buildscript -> dependencies -> classpath to,

```
// android/build.gradle
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
```

fixed the issue for me

Answer (score -1):

If you add in app.gradle under android{

```
lintOptions {

    quiet true
    abortOnError false
}
```

}

It will get work

Comment: I think it is better to fix lints and errors, if possible, instead of skip the check

Comment: It works for me in CI/CD build.