# flutter stripe stripe_payment:classpath

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate stripe payment with flutter
i have added

```
stripe_payment: ^1.0.7
```

in pubspec.yml
I am using `Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57`

I am getting the following error

```
 Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':stripe_payment:classpath'.                                   
   > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.70.                                           
     Required by:                                                                                                  
         project :stripe_payment                                                                                   
      > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.70.                                        
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.70/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.70.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.70/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.70.pom'.
               > Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/54.148.239.199, jcenter.bintray.com/52.36.128.157, jcenter.bintray.com/35.161.162.245, jcenter.bintray.com/52.88.32.158] failed: connect timed out
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':stripe_payment' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Comment: You might be running into the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482329/flutter-problems-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. I resolved the issue by changing the network. I connected to another network and app was build successfully.