# Launching Project gradle error in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle

hey i tried to run my flutter project in android studio version 4,i had problems with my SDK's for while but once i fixed my sdk problem started to face this error:

```css
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/4.1.0/builder-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find aaptcompiler-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/4.1.0/aaptcompiler-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find bundletool-0.14.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.14.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/0.14.0/bundletool-0.14.0.jar
   > Could not find manifest-merger-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/27.1.0/manifest-merger-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-gradle-api-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/27.1.0/lint-gradle-api-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find lint-model-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/27.1.0/lint-model-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find sdk-common-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/27.1.0/sdk-common-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-4.1.0-6503028.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:4.1.0-6503028).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/4.1.0-6503028/aapt2-proto-4.1.0-6503028.jar
   > Could not find crash-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:crash:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/crash/27.1.0/crash-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find gradle-api-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/4.1.0/gradle-api-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-compiler-common-4.1.0.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/4.1.0/databinding-compiler-common-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-model-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/4.1.0/builder-model-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find builder-test-api-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/4.1.0/builder-test-api-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find ddmlib-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/27.1.0/ddmlib-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find signflinger-4.1.0.jar (com.android:signflinger:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/4.1.0/signflinger-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find zipflinger-4.1.0.jar (com.android:zipflinger:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/4.1.0/zipflinger-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find tracker-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/tracker/27.1.0/tracker-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find sdklib-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/27.1.0/sdklib-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find layoutlib-api-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/27.1.0/layoutlib-api-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find dvlib-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/27.1.0/dvlib-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find repository-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/27.1.0/repository-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find shared-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/shared/27.1.0/shared-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find common-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:common:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/27.1.0/common-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
   > Could not find protos-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/27.1.0/protos-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find core-proto-0.0.2-dev.jar (com.google.test.platform:core-proto:0.0.2-dev).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/test/platform/core-proto/0.0.2-dev/core-proto-0.0.2-dev.jar
   > Could not find apkzlib-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/4.1.0/apkzlib-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find apksig-4.1.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/4.1.0/apksig-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find annotations-27.1.0.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:27.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/27.1.0/annotations-27.1.0.jar
   > Could not find databinding-common-4.1.0.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/4.1.0/databinding-common-4.1.0.jar
   > Could not find baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:4.1.0).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/4.1.0/baseLibrary-4.1.0.jar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

anyone can give me a way to fix this problem ? and will it run my project after i fixed it ? i been fixing alot of problems from installation of app till now and tried very much to run my project fixed everything and now im stuck in this level,will be great if someone can help me out here

Comment: Probably an issue with your internet. Check if you're running in offline mode

Comment: Check this link you may get your solutions.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59482329/flutter-problems-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-for-configuration-classpath