# Problem on building apk file for flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, apk

I just finished running my app and wanted to release the apk file for it however this error appears.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':flutter_local_notifications:debugUnitTestRuntimeClasspath'.

> Failed to transform bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar (org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.68) to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.

> Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\FX505DD.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.68\46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d\bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar

> Failed to transform 'C:\Users\FX505DD.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.68\46a080368d38b428d237a59458f9bc915222894d\bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: IllegalArgumentException, message: Unsupported class file major version 59. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. See [ask] for further guidance on asking questions.

Comment: im not sure to give which example because i can run and build the app just not build the apk

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/q/59482329/12838877 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright i found the best answer
just do this and it will work

**1.** - **Replace build.gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

With

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
```

**2.** - **Replaced gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

With

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
```