# How Do I Create A Path In The pubspec.yaml File?

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle, pubspec.yaml

While building an App, I came across an error:

[image]

I'm guessing the error was saying I needed to update the location package in order to use it. While researching how to update the package, I came across this website :

https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/391/android-gradle-plugin-supports-only-kotlin-gradle-plugin-version-and-heigher/

It basically said in order to update the **kotlin grade plugin version**, I would have to change the **ext.kotlin_version**'s number in the package's **android/build.gradle** file then create a path to the file in **pubspec.yaml**. I made the proper changes to location package like the website said, but the problem came when I tried creating a path to the file:

[image]

Is this even allowed? The website said to create a link straight from your computer's downloads file but Flutter isn't letting me. Are version numbers like "**1.1.1**" the only thing that can be accepted? I tried getting rid of the **path:** but that didn't work. A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Communities has not developed a stable version of the `location` package that matches the `location` package with your kotlin version. Because of that, temporary solution can be proposed. Specify the `location` package in your `pubspec.yaml` file like this. this is working for me.

replaced

```
location: ^4.4.0
```

with this in pubspec.yaml and ran flutter pub get

```
location:
git:
  url: https://github.com/781flyingdutchman/flutterlocation.git
  ref: 'V4'
  path: packages/location
```

I hope this is fixed in v4 by the maintainer of this extension soon.

Comment: The error in pubspec.yaml is gone but I still get the error when I run the debugger, I'm not sure if the path may be the problem. I'm copying & pasting it straight from the file explorer so I don't see how that can be the problem.

Comment: no!  don't do this .  you try to do what i have given in the answers above.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I try your way. I didn't change the path & I still get an error

Comment: no you don't defined  path: you can simply copy and past my answer

Comment: remove  your computer location path:

Comment: I copied it just like you said, removed the path & it still doesn't work. I'm getting the same error

Comment: after do it ran `flutter pub get` your terminal  and check your kotlin version `id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false`

Comment: In the build.gradle file, it says this - classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" , where exactly do I change the version number?

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

Comment: you can find this your `android\settings.gradle` file change to this `id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false`

Comment: When I went to the setting.gradle i added the *id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.22" apply false* to the plugins. I didn't delete anything. No when I debug, I get this error - Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.22.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.9.22)

Comment: check your internet connection and retry

Comment: i think its not a issue

Comment: Still not working

Comment: You can refer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59482329/20259506)