# Getting "Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes" error when building a release APK

Tags: flutter, apk, release

I am getting an error stating that it "Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes" because "Transform's input file does not exist". This happened while building a release APK in Flutter.

How do I fix this?

```
mianumararshad@Mians-MacBook-Pro driverSide % flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                      Note: /Users/mianumararshad/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.7/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                                                                 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.                                                         
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                                                                 
Note: /Users/mianumararshad/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator-5.3.2+2/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/tasks/LocationUpdatesUsingLocationManagerTask.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                                                               
                                                                                                                   
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                           
                                                                                                                   
* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.                                                                 
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:profileRuntimeClasspath'.                                
   > Failed to transform libs.jar to match attributes {artifactType=processed-jar, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: /Users/mianumararshad/Downloads/flutter project/roudy/driverSide/build/app/intermediates/flutter/profile/libs.jar.
         > Transform's input file does not exist: /Users/mianumararshad/Downloads/flutter project/roudy/driverSide/build/app/intermediates/flutter/profile/libs.jar. (See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158753935)
                                                                                                                   
* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                                                                   
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                                                                         
                                                                                                                   
BUILD FAILED in 6m 25s                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                           
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     387.5s (!)
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286268/error-execution-failed-for-task-app-lintvitalrelease-any-one-can-solve-it?

Answer (score 14):

Step 1. `flutter build apk --debug`

Step 2. `flutter build apk --profile`

Step 3. `flutter build apk --release`

Answer (score 12):

I have upgraded my gradle build tools `3.5.0 -> 4.0.1.` After that I was not able to make release apk. Looks like upgrading gradle build tools broke some lints.

Below solution worked for me

**Go in android folder->app->open build.gradle fine Search for lintOptions and add checkReleaseBuilds false example:**

```
lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        checkReleaseBuilds false //Insert this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's good practice or not, but hey, it works!

Comment: Adding `disable 'InvalidPackage'` did it for me, I already disabled the lint check