# React native android build fails with Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'. Could not download groovy-all-2..4.15.jar

Tags: android, react-native, groovy, pipeline, aws-codebuild

Android build using AWS CodeBuild fails with following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:lintClassPath'.
   > Could not download groovy-all-2.4.15.jar (org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.15)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.15/groovy-all-2.4.15.jar'.
            > Connection reset
```

The build works fine on my local machine. The above mentioned error occurs only while trying to build the apk using AWS CodeBuild.

If this has something to do with [jcenter shutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/jcentershut), how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Open your `build.gradle` file and add the code below under android:

android {

```
lintOptions { 
  checkReleaseBuilds false 
}
```

For more details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49286268/error-execution-failed-for-task-app-lintvitalrelease-any-one-can-solve-it)

Comment: This fixed the lint error but the build still fails with another error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68372162/android-build-fails-with-error-execution-failed-for-task-appcheckreleasedupl