# Android build fails with error: Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'

Tags: android, gradle, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, jcenter

React native Android build fails with the following error:

**Note** : The build succeeds on my local machine but fails on the pipeline using AWS Codebuild

```
> Task :app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not download rxjava-1.3.8.jar (io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.8)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.3.8/rxjava-1.3.8.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.3.8/rxjava-1.3.8.jar'.
            > Connection reset
   > Could not download dagger-library-shadow-1.7.1.jar (com.polidea.rxandroidble:dagger-library-shadow:1.7.1)
      > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/polidea/rxandroidble/dagger-library-shadow/1.7.1/dagger-library-shadow-1.7.1.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/polidea/rxandroidble/dagger-library-shadow/1.7.1/dagger-library-shadow-1.7.1.jar'.
            > Connection reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the build agent cannot find the resources, which is probably caused by using jcenter: jcenter() is deprectaded and will be discontinued soon, try to migrate to mavenCentral(), that should fix the issues.