# Error generating signed apk with nothing in lint-results-release-fatal

Tags: java, gradle

I've got the same error as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098494/error-when-generate-signed-apk) question, but there's nothing in lint-results-release-fatal.xml (or htlm) as answers suggest. How can it be?
Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:

```
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, prorem was developing in flutter, the solution was to access the build.gradle file and add the following:

```
    android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

}
```