# Error display where generate singed APK from android studio

Tags: android, apk

Lint found fatal errors while assembling a release target.

To proceed, either fix the issues identified by lint, or modify your build script as follows:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add more from log? What issues did lint find?

Comment: check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/24098494/9408181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change on build.gradle file inside android {} like below

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard- 
           rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

}
```

Comment: While this will make the error disappear, lint errors usually indicate that there's something wrong with the application and one should attempt first to fix the error causing the lint error to appear.