# FLUTTER: Unable to release. Error on line 1005

Tags: flutter

I get this error when I try to make a release APK or bundle.  When I run for debug everything goes smoothly - Anyone got any ideas?

**Result of `run --release --verbose`**

```
[   +1 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +1 ms] * Where:
[        ] Script
'..\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005[   +1 ms] * What went wrong:
[        ] Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.
[        ] > Process 'command '..\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finishedwith non-zero exit value 1
[   +1 ms] * Try:
[   +1 ms] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug optionto get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[        ] BUILD FAILED in 38s
```

I get the same error for a completely new project, with no edits

Comment: what command do you use; Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug optionto get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: I used `run --release --verbose` - with `--stacktrace` I only get recommendations to upgrade libraries to support future gradle versions

Comment: try this command => flutter build apk --release -vv

Comment: @AwiasRehman the result of that looks identical with `run --release --verbose`

Comment: is this all errors ?

Comment: @AwiasRehman unfortunately yes... Red, all so red

Comment: Follow This => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66758163/flutter-build-apk-error-execution-failed-for-task-appcompileflutterbuildrele

Answer (score 0):

Doing "flutter build apk --no-shrink" works for me