# Flutter build failed Exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.lint.client.api.Vendor

Tags: flutter

I am using this command to create build

```
flutter build apk  --split-per-abi  --no-sound-null-safety --no-tree-shake-icons --no-shrink -v
```

i am using flutter version 2.5.0

I am getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.lint.client.api.Vendor
[        ]  at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:328)
[        ]  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
[        ]  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

How can i resolve this issue to create build?

Comment: Your title (OutOfMemoryError) does not match the question details.

Answer (score 15):

Added this

```
lintOptions { 

    checkReleaseBuilds false

}
```

in android/app/build.gradle seems to resolve this issue.
Got it from this link

[':app:lintVitalRelease' error when generating signed apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24098494/applintvitalrelease-error-when-generating-signed-apk)